# Having issues using existing Entrust certificates for Jetty SSL connection

Tags: ssl, https, jetty

I have three files from Entrust: *.csr, *.key and *.crt.

So far:

1. I have brought the *.key and *.crt into a PKCS12 keystore using OpenSSL
2. I have imported the *.pkcs12 into a keystore using keytool
3. Using this technique, I am able to use an SSL connection with Jetty

However, I'm getting a Certificate Error in IE (unsecured items in Chrome).

In our case, the certificates are currently being used for domain:80 (Apache) and I'm attempting to "reuse" them for domain:8443 (Jetty).

Am I wrong in thinking that I can use these for Jetty as well? On the same IP/domain, but on a different port and webserver? My gut is telling me that one of these files relates to Entrust recognizing Apache (*.csr) and that I should have to do the same for Jetty?

**Edit #1**

The error goes as follow:

```
Certificate Error

Untrusted Certificate

The security certificate presented by this webiste was not issued by a trusted certificate authority

This problem may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.

We recommend that you close this webpage.
```

But yet Chrome, sees it as valid. I does have to work on IE since it's our standard.

**Edit #2**

1. Chrome doesn't complain
2. Nor does Firefox

**Edit #3**

I found our CA certificate specified in the Apache conf file. I then proceeded to concatenate our cert with the CA cert into a PKCS12 file. Then, using keytool, I generated the keystore.

I loaded it on the server, rebooted and viewed in IE. IE still shows a certificate issue.

In the concatenated file, I see in this order: our cert and then 2 other certificates.

On a side note, I called Entrust and the CSR saw no problems as he was using IE 8. We're on IE7.

**Edit #4**

Using this command:

```
keytool -list -keystore keystore -v
```

It shows 3 certificates (in this order):

1. Ours
2. Owner: CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C,
3. Owner: CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)

**Edit 5**

Solved! I guess I had a caching issue. Confirmed with colleagues.

Answer, Concatenating all my certs, including the CA cert, into the keystore solved my issue.

Comment: @GregS See edits, I added the specific error.

Comment: The port or the application are irrelevant as far as the certificate is concerned. You can use the same certificate on all 65000 ports each  with a different application listening if you want. I don't have enough information to diagnose this any further. I can only suggest you examine more carefully the certificate setup you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port number, as stated in the comments, is irrelevant for trusting an SSL/TLS connection.

The problem is that the entire certificate chain from your certificate up to the Entrust root probably looks like this

```
your cert - intermediate CA 1 - intermediate CA 2 - ... - root CA
```

To make this work for IE you have to import not only your certificate into the PKCS#12 container, but additionally the intermediate certificates and also the root certificate. Otherwise your SSL implementation won't be able to provide the full path during the SSL handshake and thus IE has no means to build a proper chain to compare to its set of trusted root certificates.

So my advise would be to get the intermediate certificates from the appropriate web sites and importing them with `keytool` into your PKCS#12 key store.

Once done, IE should from then on accept without complaining.

Comment: This file wouldn't be the *.csr, that I already have, would it? Also, since we got it from Entrust directly, I thought there wasn't any intermediates?

Comment: The .csr is the PKCS#10 certificate signing request, this could be your initial request, then there's no additional information or it could also be the signed response signed by Entrust. In that case you could look there for the certificates. Try `openssl req -in myreq.csr -noout -text` and `openssl pkcs7 -in myreq.csr -print_certs -noout` to see what's in there. No CA will issue end user certificates directly under a root CA. They will always have sub CAs under their root which issue the actual certificate, so chances are high that you still need intermediate certificates.

Comment: I found our CA cert. I concatenated it with our own cert, recreated the PKCS12 file and used keytool to generate the keystore. IE still complains. Your first command you posted showed some information. The second created an error.